# Capturing content in server side from nicEdit when form is submitted in asp.net website

Tags: c#, nicedit

I am using nicedit in my asp page. I am developing a website using asp.net. I managed to get the nicedit work, but how can I get the value of the textarea, I want to store the value in the DB when submit button is clicked. Actually I am trying to get the textarea value in my server side code(c#).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nicEdit.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
        try {
            new nicEditor({ fullPanel: true }).panelInstance('bee');
        }
        catch (ex)
      { }
    });
   //]]> 
</script> 

 <textarea id="bee" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the results of the entered data, you need to pass the ID of the textarea. 
See below:

```
data = new nicEditors.findEditor('bee'); // bee is the ID of the textarea
d = data.getContent(); // return the content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the textarea by the `Value` property

```
string val = bee.Value
```